# trigger a bootstrap modal with a param not a button in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am really stuck trying to figure this out.  I am trying to trigger a confirmation modal on my index page after destroying a record. Once I destroy a record on the delete page I want to redirect to the index page and automatically create a "Congratulations, you've deleted a record".  I do not want to use alerts...I would like to use a modal.

Thanks in advance!

this is some of what I've tried (my Modal has the id #destroyedSuccess)

```
  <%= link_to "Delete Project", records_path, :class => "btn",  :remote => true, "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "#destroyedSuccess"%>

<%= link_to "Delete Project", records_path,  "data-toggle" => "modal", 'data-target' => '#destroyedSuccess' %>
```

Comment: I just posted what I still have. I haven't saved all my trys as I did even know if I was in the right ballpark with some of them.

Answer (score 1):

Try to trigger modal in you `app/views/records/destroy.js.erb` file by js.

> $("#destroyedSuccess").modal()

You can pass other options in hash to modal also.

if you redirecting to index action then you need to trigger it respective file through js.

Comment: I don't have a app/views/records/destroy.js.erb.  I don't understand...am I to create a whole JS file with just the one line of javascript?  I use rails destroy method to destroy records.

Comment: If you are using ajax request to destroy the records then rails by default(if you have not mentioned other thing to do) try to render destroy.js.erb, in which you can trigger the modal.